# How to grant setuid permission to sudo

Tags: linux-kernel, sudo, setuid

So, I'm building my own Linux distribution and I've set up quite a lot, including sudo. Working from a shroot environment, sudo works well, the problem is when i actually boot into my distro. Originally, when I saw that the /usr/bin/sudo executable just needed setuid permission, I thought, "Well, easy fix," and proceeded to set the permission for the executable using `chmod s+u /usr/bin/sudo`.

When I check the executable's permissions with `ls -l`, it easily indicates that it has the setuid permission. When I first exited out of chroot and checked, the executable didn't have the steuid permission, so I set it again. Now it does show having the setuid permission both in chroot and out of it. The problem comes in when I try to boot the OS. The OS boots just fine, but unfortunately, the sudo executable for some reason doesn't have the setuid permission. I suspect it has something to do with grub-mkrescue, which I'm using to create the ISO, as I think the permission might be getting lost along the way of grub-mkrescue copying the files to a temporal directory before building the ISO. I don't really care about grub modules, and if I needed them, I have an easy way of copying them manually, so it's okay even if a working solution means losing access to the modules, I just need a way to create an ISO image without first copying the files to a temporary directory, oh, and the solution needs to have the ISO be packaged with Grub. I know there are other bootloaders out there, so suggestions which have me using another bootloader are welcome.

Comment: Note: if you want to create you own distribution, you should become an expert of an existing distro (and so know where to look): else you will lose most of time for problems which were solved years ago. (and it is full of corner cases, in your case I assume it is about filesystem) -- maybe a "blend" is much better then recreating a full distro (and there is much more documentation).